# How to expand table row data with Keen io?

Tags: keen-io

I have a requirement to draw a summery table of  events, which only shows some of the properties. When a user clicks on one of the table rows, it needs to expand to  the full details of selected event.

I am currently using "table" chartType.
Can I utilize the exiting keen-js to do that? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Keen.js uses Google Charts under the hood create the table and is limited by what Google Charts tables can do. Unfortunately, it doesn't look like this is possible. You can use Keen.js to make the query for the data, but visualizing it in the way that you're looking for won't be possible with Keen.js.

This jQuery plugin may of interest to you though: http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/expand-table-rows-with-jquery-jexpand-plugin/

Comment: Thanks Eric for the link. It's very helpful.